# Highcharts - custom rangeSelector button and change xAxis from hourly to date

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I can not update and change chart's axis label and data in a chart with a custom range selector button

I have a custom button for range selector and I want to update and change chart with more data and new axis

old `xAxis` is showing with an hourly label (e.g. 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17)
and when I select another range selector button `xAxis` should showing with date label (e.g. 10 Mar, 10 Apr, 10 May) but it not

I have used `.setExtremes()` but `xAxis` label is gone nothing showing
I have used `.update({})` for update formatter but formatter can assign only 1 value and then `xAxis` show only one day for all label (e.g. 11 May, 11 May, 11 May)

```
let mainDate = new Date(indexGraph.xAxis[0].dataMax);

if (range == "Date") {
  var maxDate = mainDate.setDate(mainDate.getDate());
  var minDate = mainDate.setDate(mainDate.getDate() - count);
} else if (range == "Month") {
  var maxDate = mainDate.setMonth(mainDate.getMonth());
  var minDate = mainDate.setMonth(mainDate.getMonth() - count);
}

indexGraph.xAxis[0].update({
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      if ($("#renageSelectorDiv > div.selected")[0].id !== "1-day") {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat("%e %b", this.value);
      } else {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat("%H", this.value);
      }
    }
  }
});
indexGraph.xAxis[0].setExtremes(minDate, maxDate);
```

I want to know how I can change it to correct?
or what is the best way to change and update axis(both `yAxis` and `xAxis`) and chart

Comment: Hi @m.atp, Could you provide us with some minimal live example on jsfiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: here you are https://jsfiddle.net/g1vmu8fc/2/
it's doesn't work maybe data for render is not correct

Comment: I do not know what your concept is, but the `x` values are in range 1 - 100 and a `datetime` axis uses milliseconds. You should changle the values, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uoLkjrg9/

Comment: I'm so sorry about that example. My concept is render graph that show stock price in 1 day, 1 month or 6 month, so I don't know how to show you example with so much more data like I'm using
I saw your example and I don't know why my code still doesn't work
thank you for your example.
but, Would you mine if I asking you to see and give me some example with this code https://jsfiddle.net/wu9za5jm/1/

Comment: Hi @m.atp, The problem is still related to `x` data values. Please try to create an example with some part of your real data.